# Mocking external REST endpoint in Arquillian

Tags: java, rest, jboss-arquillian, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to test my application, which sends a REST request to a server and retrieves some fileNames. I'm trying to deploy the following two classes:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {

}
```

and

```
@Path("/files")
@RequestScoped
public class RestEndpointMock {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getFileNames() {
        return new MockResponse();
    }

    private class MockResponse extends Response {

        @Override
        public Object getEntity() {
            return new MockEntity();
        }
    }

    private class MockEntity implements HttpEntity {

        @Override
        public InputStream getContent() throws IOException, UnsupportedOperationException {
        return ByteArrayInputStream(fileNamesAsJson.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
    }
}
```

The aim is when the actual usecase sends a REST request, this mocked interface is hit and it returns the mocked list of file names instead.

I'm building up the request as follows (for the test call, to disable SSL certificate errors):

```
public static HttpClient createHttpClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

    // set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
    }, new SecureRandom());

    final SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
    final Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);
    final SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);

    final ClientConnectionManager cm = new SingleClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);
    final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
    return httpClient;
}
```

Then finally sending the request as:

```
private HttpResponse sendPostRequest(){
    final HttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient();
    final String postUrl = String.format(https://localhost/login);
    final HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(postUrl);
    return httpClient.execute(postRequest)
}
```

But I end up getting a ConnectionRefused exception when attempting this way. Unsure if I've set up the mocked endpoint incorrectly, or if something else is messed up along the way.

Comment: You should take a look at http://wiremock.org/

Comment: Or hoverfly there are several ways to mock http server thing. But in case of using Arquillian I suspect that you are using incontainer mode and not injecting the URL where everything is deployed, can you share a github project with this?